# How to effectively clear/rest a form?

Tags: jquery, forms, ajaxform

I have a form with `textarea`, some `input[type=text]` and other `input[type=file]`. I submit the form via Jquery Form plugin, and I've unable to then clear/rest the form, by any means. I tried the clearFrom and resetForm form plugin options and some other and none seem to work

HTML

```
<form action="validade_main_cenas.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="post-cenas-form" id="post-cenas-form" name="post_cenas_form">
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <label>cenas</label>
            <textarea name="cenas" rows="" class="ask_cenas_form_input_question" placeholder="cenas your cenas..."></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="image-post-container" id="image-post-container">
                <div id="image-post-preview" class="image-post-preview">
                    <img id="image-preview" name="image-preview" class="image-preview" src="#">
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Tags</label>
            <input id="tags" name="tags" class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="e.g cenas">
        </fieldset>
        <div id="" class="footer">
            <div id="" class="footer-post-image">
                <button type="button" id="yourBtn" class="btn" onclick="getFile()"><i class="icon-camera"></i> 
                </button>
                <div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
                    <input id="upfile" type="file" name="myfile" value="upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="" class="footer-submit-button">
                <input type="submit" id="cenas_it" class="btn btn-hunch" value="Hunch" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- close footer !-->
    </div>
    <!-- wrapper para quando existe imagem !-->
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getFile() {
        document.getElementById("upfile").click();
    }

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('#image-preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#upfile").change(function() {
        readURL(this);
        $('#image-post-container').slideDown('fast');
    });
</script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/load_questions.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = { 
        clearForm: true,
        resetForm: true,
        success: function (html) {
            $("ol#list-feed").prepend(html);
            $("ol#list-feed li:first").slideDown(600);
            $("ol#list-feed li div.footer-post").hide();
            resetForm($('#post-cenas-form'));
            document.getElementById('set-width1').reset();
            document.getElementById('upfile').reset();
            document.getElementById('tags').reset();
            //document.getElementById('set-width1').val('');
            //document.getElementById('tags').val('');
            if ($("ol#list-feed > li").size() <= 3) {
                $('#loadmorebutton').hide();
            } else {
                $("ol#list-feed > li:last").remove();
                $('#loadmorebutton').show();
            }
            $('form#post-cenas-form')[0].reset();
            //$("#post-cenas-form").resetForm();
            //$(this).children(':input').val('');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR: unable to upload files');
        },
        complete: function () {
            resetForm($('#post-cenas-form'));
            document.getElementById('set-width1').reset();
            document.getElementById('upfile').reset();
            document.getElementById('tags').reset();
            //$('form#post-cenas-form')[0].reset();
            //$(this).children(':input').val('');
        },
    };
    $("#post-cenas-form").ajaxForm(options);
    function resetForm($form) {
        $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
        $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
        .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('#post-cenas-form')[0].reset();` should be more than enough. get rid of the rest.

Comment: I had tried it before. Nevertheless, I followed your suggestion adding $('form#post-question-form')[0].reset(); to both "success" and "complete" and no effect. Can you imagine what might be happening?

Comment: Thank you Kevin B! That will be very helpful for me too! I usually make a button and a click function with a bunch of "set values to "" " - :-)

Comment: Watch your console, are you seeing any errors? Many of the lines where you attempted to do it other ways that come before that line could possibly be throwing errors which would prevent the last one from working.

Comment: console (only thing) --> type error: document.getElementById(...) is null --> pointing to jquery 1.9.1

Comment: well, working now...kind of strange since I haven't done any important change. thanks to all

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

`$('#FORM-ID').reset();`

**UPDATE**:
Forgot to mention that you should extend jQuery with this function:

```
    jQuery.fn.reset = function () {
       $(this).each (function() { this.reset(); });
    }
```

Comment: Add it on button click or something

Comment: No, you can't. jQuery objects do not support a `reset()` method. `<form>` DOM elements do.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thank you, I have updated the comment, this should work now :)

Comment: Yes, it will indeed. In passing, if you want to extend jQuery instead of accessing the underlying DOM element, you should keep in mind `this` is already a jQuery object and you should aim to preserve chaining if possible. Therefore, the body of `$.fn.reset()` should rather be `return this.each(function() { this.reset(); });` (and you also probably should check if `reset()` is actually supported by the current element).